# AWS S3 problem with docker using asp net core mvc

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, docker, asp.net-core, amazon-s3

I am trying to run my microservice app (Asp Net Core) with docker and trying to get it work with Amazon AWS S3 Buckets. I am a totally Noob using Amazon AWS so I read the documentation and made this work but without docker and now I am trying to use it with docker but cannot make this work.

I have a file called `credenciales.txt` inside my project folder that stores my amazon credentials like access keys:

```
[myprofilename]
aws_access_key_id=myAccessKey
aws_secret_access_key=mySecretKey
```

This is my appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "ApiSettings": {
    "GatewayAddress": "http://localhost:5000"
  },
  "ElasticConfiguration": {
    "Uri": "http://localhost:9200"
  },

  "AWS": {
    "Profile": "myprofilename",
    "Region": "us-east-2",
    "ProfilesLocation": "credenciales.txt"
  },

  "ConfigKeys": {
    "AwsBucketName": "bucketName",
    "AwsS3BaseUrl": "amazonaws",
    "AwsRegion": "us-east-2",
    "FileSize": "2000000"
  },

  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

When running the app with `dotnet run --urls=https://localhost:7888` and tried to upload a file to amazon S3 Bucket it Worked!!!

but when trying to run it with docker with `docker-compose up` and attempt to upload a file to amazon S3 it does not work, it is likely because it cannot get the credentials file(I think).

This is my docker file from the project that I am trying to make aws work:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Apps/Web/ASPNET/Sistema/Sistema.csproj", "Apps/Web/ASPNET/Sistema/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Apps/Web/ASPNET/Sistema/Sistema.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Apps/Web/ASPNET/Sistema"
RUN dotnet build "Sistema.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Sistema.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Sistema.dll"]
```

docker files from src, docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'

services:
    sistema:
        image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}sistema
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Apps/Web/ASPNET/Sistema/Dockerfile
```

**docker-compose.override.yml**

```
version: '3.4'

services:

    inventario.api:
        container_name: inventario.api
        environment:
            - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
            - "DatabaseSettings:ConnectionString=Server=myServer;Port=myPort;Database=myDatabase;User Id=myUser;Password=HelloWorld;"
            - "ElasticConfiguration:Uri=http://elasticsearch:9200"
        depends_on:
            - inventariodb
        ports:
            - "5035:80"

    ocelotapigw:
        container_name: ocelotapigw
        environment:
            - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
            - "ElasticConfiguration:Uri=http://elasticsearch:9200"
        depends_on:
            - inventario.api
        ports:
            - "5000:80"

    sistema:
        container_name: sistema
        environment:
            - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
            - "ApiSettings:GatewayAddress=http://ocelotapigw"
            - "ElasticConfiguration:Uri=http://elasticsearch:9200"
        depends_on:
            - ocelotapigw
            - inventario.api
        ports:
            - "1235:80"
```

How do I make this work using docker? Do I have to use Amazon AWS CLI or something like that?

PD: The app is in development and I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with VS Code. I am planning to deploy the microservice app to amazon EKS later few months.

Comment: consider configuring your S3 client using environment variables instead of a file

Comment: Have you tried adding the credentials to a directory named .aws located in the home directory of the user that owns and runs the application in the container ( as opposed to the projects directory )?

Comment: Daniels solution is probably better

Comment: Did what Daniel said and worked BUT not for docker, Do I need code the path of .aws files inside docker files? because gave me this error: `AmazonClientException: No RegionEndpoint or ServiceURL configured`